# Cannot get Python perspective with Eclipse IDE

Tags: macos, python, eclipse

I installed PyDev for Eclipse, but after doing so, I do not see PyDev in the list of perspectives. If I try to reinstall, it says it is already installed.

Running Mac OSX 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) and tried both Kepler and Juno releases of Eclipse (installed from www.eclipse.org), and PyDev latest from www.pydev.org, using the same procedures I use under Ubuntu (adding the site under "Install New Software").

I'm running Java runtime 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609.

Any idea as to how I can get this working, so that I can get to a Python perspective in Eclipse?

Comment: It works for me. Do you see it listed in Eclipse → Preferences → General → Perspectives? Or when creating a new project, do you see "PyDev Project" available? If not, maybe try "eclipse -clean" from the command line as suggested in [this answer]( http://stackoverflow.com/a/1529591/2934386)

Comment: Yeah, nothing in perspectives. No PYDev project type. Tried on two machines. Only thing in common is OS version, and they had older version of Eclipse. Works find on Ubuntu boxes. I'll try the clean and report back.

Comment: eclipse -clean made no difference.

Comment: I followed the same steps and tried installing PyDev 2.x, but the PyDev didn't show up in the preferences or perspective. I am using Python 2.7 and java 6. Any work around?

Answer (score 1):

Found out from someone at work...

Turns out that PyDev 3.x needs Java 7. Since I have Java 6, I need PyDev 2.x. I uninstalled, and then re-installed (unchecking the box that shows only the latest version) and now the PyDev perspective appears.